# Ошибка A java exception has occurred

Tags: java

Ошибка вылетает сразу после запуска системы.
Приложение Java переустанавливал - не помогло.
В чем может быть причина.
ОС Windows 7 x32

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: До этого джава была и работала?

Comment: Понятия не имею честно сказать.. в офисе стоит комп, просто бесит уже эта ошибка, убрать бы ее просто и все, на работу пк никак не влияет вообще

Comment: Раз сразу после запуска, то проверяйте автозагрузку и login-скрипты, где-то там прописан запуск какой-то Java программы. А дальше надо либо убирать её, либо запускать в консоли, смотреть stack trace возникающего исключения и разбираться с ним.